# JMX from Spring @ Tomcat using Java based Config

Tags: java, mbeans, spring-jmx

I like to see the hibernate statistics but cant find them.

Where do i have to search?

```
@Bean
@Lazy
public MBeanExporter getExporter() {
    MBeanExporter exporter = new MBeanExporter();
    exporter.setServer(mBeanFactory());
    exporter.setRegistrationBehavior(MBeanExporter.REGISTRATION_REPLACE_EXISTING);
    HashMap beans = new HashMap();
    beans.put("hibernate:name=statistics", hibernateStatistics());
    exporter.setBeans(beans);
    return exporter;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this ? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708602/how-to-configure-hibernate-statistics-in-spring-3-0-application

Comment: No, javac sais: <bean is not a valid java identifier! (lol)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the jmxbean should be on root.

I had do mark the hibernateStatistics()-Bean to be @DependsOn("hibernate").

[image]